# Form Edit URL by Java Script

Tags: javascript

I am using this script for make edit URL of a Form. But it stops working after two or three days until I copy and paste this script with a new function name.

```js
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var columnIndex = headers[0].indexOf(columnName);
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL);

for (var i = startRow - 1; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i][0] != '' && data[i][columnIndex] == '') {
    var timestamp = data[i][0];
    var formSubmitted = form.getResponses(timestamp);
    
    if (formSubmitted.length < 1) continue;
    
    var editResponseUrl = formSubmitted[0].getEditResponseUrl();
    
    sheet.getRange(i + 1, columnIndex + 1).setValue(editResponseUrl);
  }
}

}
```

Comment: Stuff usually doesn't stop working on its own after a few days. So what is the _context_ here? Which environment does this run in? What function name that you are changing to make it work again, are you talking about to begin with, I don't see any?

Comment: what is the question?